# How many Ubuntu VMs can I reasonably expect to run using KVM on a Dell R410 Xeon 5645 with 24 GB of RAM

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I am working on an infrastructure refresh for the company I work for and I need to do capacity planning.  My boss felt somewhat burned by VMs he purchased from a hosting company not living up to the performance level expected, so any capacity numbers for KVM VMs that I can use as a basis for my calculations are appreciated.

Comment: capacity-planning would be a good tag for this but I don't have the rep to create it.

Comment: Have you checked this http://serverfault.com/questions/61414/complete-infrastructure-capacity-planning-exercise

Comment: I have not, but the link to 'The Art of Capacity Planning' is a good one and I will be taking a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how busy they will be and how much ram you plan on allocating to them.  For a basic setup, I would consider 1-2 gb for each vm, so you should be able to run 10-20 if they aren't heavily cpu bound.

Comment: Thanks!  They aren't CPU bound and actually don't have much external traffic load.  The 1-2 GB Ram was the missing piece.

Answer (score 1):

The art of capacity-planning is not an exact science - it does depend on several inputs - chief amongst which are:

1. What OS are you intending to run
2. What will the OS be running 50% of the time
3. What is the expected memory usage for that 50%
4. What is the expected CPU usage for that 50%
5. How much Host RAM
6. How much Host CPU - roughly cores multiplied by number of processors

The target you should be looking at is roughly 75% CPU & Memory Usage for all VM instances.

KVM does have fairly good memory management and as such you can overallocate [balloon] memory that would be made available by the host.

Red-Hat/Cent OS have a similar feature as VMWare ESX where KVM can page in/page out memory segments shared by different OS's - hence you can squeeze even more VMs.

Thus - lets assume you are running 11.04 desktop for each VM instance.  The majority of the work is users using Firefox & LibreOffice - taking up, say half of the required memory (Ubuntu minimum is a recommended 1GB), but little in the way of CPU usage.  I would expect (wet finger in the air) for a 24GB host to be able to run 32 VM's.  On Red-Hat/Cent OS - you perhaps could increase this to 48 VM's.

Again - not an exact science, but not knowing what the chief areas (1 to 6 above) are, just an educated guess.